# What is "no matching function for call to 'println(decode_results*)'"?

Tags: arduino

I have an example piece of code and I want to print the variables to the log, specifically a variable named `&results` I wrote a line in the code at the end of `void loop()` to print the variable to the serial print out.

This isn't the full code but a large segment at least.

```
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("IR Receiver Button Decode"); 
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver

}/*--(end setup )---*/


void loop()   /*----( LOOP: RUNS CONSTANTLY )----*/
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // have we received an IR signal? &results is 
  the variable
  Serial.println(&results)   //<-- My line of code

  {
    translateIR(); 
    irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value
  }  
}/* --(end main loop )-- */
```

I expected the output to be the variable's content but it spat out `no matching function for call to "println(decode_results*)"` whilst compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply use Arduino's [print](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) to print C structs. You can only print simple C data types like float, String, int, etc. So you need to print each field of your struct separately. I don't know `decode_results` but you can print its fields with something like this:

```
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("IR Receiver Button Decode");
    irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver

} /*--(end setup )---*/

void loop() /*----( LOOP: RUNS CONSTANTLY )----*/
{
    if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // have we received an IR signal? &results is the variable
    {
        Serial.print("Results: ");
        Serial.print(results.field1); // first field
        Serial.print(" , ");
        Serial.println(results.field2); // second field
    }
    translateIR();
    irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value
} /* --(end main loop )-- */
```

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov As I know if you use to print on a struct it will become `Undefined_behavior`. So what is the point of printing the structure object?! I'm not sure about OP's `decode_results` but I'm sure if he wants to print it he should print each element individually.